# Perforce auto resolve from the command line?

Tags: perforce, p4v

P4V has been crapping out on me when attempting to resolve a large number of files as part of an integration.  I want to be able to do this in the command line.

Here's the steps in P4V:

1. Right-click the CL.
2. Choose "Resolve Files..." A dialog will appear.
3. Choose "Merge yours and theirs if no conflicts exist".
4. Click Auto.

Can someone translate this into a p4 command line command with correct arguments?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `p4 resolve -am [file ...]` which will skip the files with conflicts.

If you specify a file, you will work on that file only.  If you specify `...`, you will work on files below your working directory.  If you do not specify a file, it will work on all of the files in your workspace.

Comment: It's not possible to specify a Pending CL for the files with the resolve command?

Comment: No, it doesnt seem so.  One option is to wrap it in a `for` loop in a batch, taking the changelist from the command line and iterating over the files returned by `p4 describe changelist#`, passing them to `p4 resolve -am`

Comment: I'd rather use `p4 resolve -as`. As it only resolves if it's safe to do so. The `-am` option merges too, which may cause merge errors, I'd rather do that manually in p4merge.

Comment: is there a way to do this but when there is actual conflict - open p4 UI same way as without -am option? I'd like to integrate this tool with my git workflow. Currently I have to close-save all the conflicts if P4 thinkgs there is no conflict. But if I specify -am this means, I will not see any UI in case of conflict either...

Answer (score 12):

I do not have enough reputation to add a comment to the accepted answer so I'll add information in a new answer.

With Perforce 2013.2 you can indeed provide a changelist number to resolve to limit the operation to the files in that changelist.

```
p4 resolve -c changelist#
```

Answer (score 1):

I follow these steps, to do it from command line.

1. In perforce client, Select the folder in workspace.
2. Select File -> Open Terminal Window Here.Terminal will open in the same directory which is selcted in step 1.
3. Perform a **dry run** using option *-n* :

> p4 resolve -c 1234 -n

5. To accept automatic merge from perforce use *-am* option, *`Automatic Mode. Automatically accept the recommended file revision: if theirs is identical to base, accept yours; if yours is identical to base, accept     theirs; if yours and theirs are different from base, and there are no conflicts between yours and theirs; accept merge; otherwise, there are conflicts between yours and theirs, so skip this file.`*

> p4 resolve -c 1234 -am