# How to resolve a lot of files? The individual resolve option is disabled

Tags: perforce

I have a huge project. After a merge I got a conflict - approx 1500 files need to be resolved. Most of this files are binaries and I can just accept source. But there are also a few text files that needs to be resolved and I want to merge them manually. In p4v when I'm clicking `resolve` option the resolve window appears with a list of files. The option `Interactively resolve files one at a time` is disabled. `Safe automatic resolve (no merging)` doesn't work and all I can do is `Accept source` what I don't want because of several text file conflicts.

Comment: Do some p4 magic in console:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188491/perforce-auto-resolve-from-the-command-line

Comment: Thanks. This command gave me nothing, but after it `Interactively resolve files one at a time` button became enabled.